# How can I user_access()?

Tags: 8

How can I use [`user_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_access/7.x) in Drupal 8?

Comment: Did you check the documentation on api.drupal.org? There is a [comment](https://api.drupal.org/comment/57348#comment-57348). api.drupal.org and drupal.org should be the first places to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is, you can't. It doesn't exist in D8.
The longer answer is you use a method on the current user as follows:

```
\Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission([PERMISSION NAME]);
```

You can read the change record here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2049309